# Is it possible to map a matrix to a igraph object?

Tags: r, polygon, igraph

I have a matrix  `A` that define ordered segments of a self-intersecting polygon:

```
A <- t(matrix(c(
         0,  0  ,
         1,  0  ,
         1, -2  ,
        -2, -2  ,
        -2, -1  ,
         0, -1  ,
         0, -4  ,
        -1, -4  ,
        -1, -2  ,
         2, -2  ,
         2, -3  ,
         0, -3  ,
         0, 0), nrow = 2));

par(mfrow=c(1,3)) 

plot(A, col='red', type= 'l', xlim=c(min(A[,1]),max(A[,1])),
      ylim=c(min(A[,2]),max(A[,2])), xlab='x', ylab='y'); 
points(A, col='black', pch = 22); 
grid()
```

I heed to map the matrix `A` to an undirected graph where a point `(x,y)`  corresponds to a vertex and a segment between the "*neighboring*" points corresponds to an edge. The neighboring points (by distance but not id's number) connected by red lines on the right fugure.

**Edit.**  After the user20650's comment I have mapped the matrix to the undirected graph (middle graph on the figure). The undirected graph looks like an expected result. But with the `edge.curved=TRUE`option (rigth fugure) we see the edges `(3,4)`, `(6,7)`, `(9,10)` and `(12, 13)`.

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_empty_graph(n=nrow(A)); 
g <- g + path(seq_len(nrow(A))); 
plot(as.undirected(g), layout=as.matrix(A))
plot(g, layout=as.matrix(A), edge.curved=TRUE)
```

The length of edges must be equal to 1. Based on the condition we should add `5` vetries to the graph `g` and corresponded edges.

I can delete the edge `(3,4)` and add edges `(3,9)` and `(9,4)` and so on for pairs `(12, 13)`, `(9,10)` and `(6,7)`.

**Question.** Is there exist a way to such mapping?

[image]

Comment: does this do what you want; `library(igraph) ; g <- make_empty_graph(n=nrow(A)) ; g <- g + path(seq_len(nrow(A))) ; plot(g, layout=as.matrix(A))`

Comment: I have added a remark to my original question. Is it possible to add extra vertex that defines by intersections of two segments?

Comment: which vertices is the extra vertex is connected to? can you do it manually with `add_vertices`, `add_edges`?

Comment: In your graph the extra vertex should be connected with 3, 6, 9 and 12. Of course I can add manually a new vertex. Is it possible to do automatically because edges are "crossed"?

Comment: okay. so that makes me think the code in my earlier comment
is not what you want. The path from vertex 3 (1, -2) to vertex 4 (-2, -2) 
passes through vertex 9 (-1, -2) but there is not an edge between them. Similarly 7 and 12 etc

Comment: @user20650, I have re-written the question and added some details.